# Cryptojs AES decryption of byte array with key and iv result is 0 in javascript

Tags: javascript, cryptojs

I need to decrypt .net encrypted code to decrypt in js. When I convert it to WordArray and decrypt
it, I am getting 0 array. Here is the code. Thank you for your help.

```
cipherText = [132, 185, 138, 129, 38, 216, 49, 48, 25, 139, 187, 146, 67, 234, 194, 143, 252, 214, 245, 230, 30, 238, 235, 53, 155, 136, 0, 112, 76, 27, 205, 84, 124, 250, 74, 114, 208, 227, 148, 135, 112, 168, 171, 73, 45, 122, 31, 248, 186, 80, 148, 143, 251, 216, 90, 152, 138, 130, 148, 199, 178, 151, 151, 195, 252, 43, 67, 183, 45, 24, 228, 73, 208, 249, 155, 36, 78, 232, 210, 20, 235, 109, 206, 245, 180, 28, 227, 32, 202, 143, 255, 110, 128, 38, 101, 174, 253, 80, 171, 201......]
Key = [56, 63, 82, 186, 73, 8, 112, 110, 129, 185, 157, 192, 163, 160, 120, 215, 52, 254, 252, 189, 25, 82, 43, 15, 87, 98, 48, 193, 21, 44, 6, 163];
IV = [200, 97, 110, 6, 23, 248, 144, 210, 223, 167, 67, 64, 125, 96, 136, 201];
var strHexWA = CryptoJS.enc.Hex.parse(CryptoJS.lib.WordArray.create(new Uint8Array(cipherText)));             
        var KeyWA = CryptoJS.enc.Hex.parse(CryptoJS.lib.WordArray.create(new Uint8Array(Key)));
        var IVWA = CryptoJS.enc.Hex.parse(CryptoJS.lib.WordArray.create(new Uint8Array(IV)));
        var decrypt = CryptoJS.AES.decrypt(strHexWA, KeyWA, {
            iv: IVWA
        });   
var plaintext = CryptoJS.enc.UTF8.stringify(decrypt);
        console.log(plaintext )
```

Encription Code in .net :

```
    protected static byte[] EncryptStringToBytes_Aes(string plainText, byte[] Key, byte[] IV)
{
// Check arguments.
if (plainText == null || plainText.Length <= 0)
throw new ArgumentNullException("plainText");
if (Key == null || Key.Length <= 0)
throw new ArgumentNullException("Key");
if (IV == null || IV.Length <= 0)
throw new ArgumentNullException("IV");
byte[] encrypted;
// Create an AesManaged object
// with the specified key and IV.
using (AesManaged aesAlg = new AesManaged())
{
aesAlg.Key = Key;
aesAlg.IV = IV;
// Create a decrytor to perform the stream transform.
ICryptoTransform encryptor = aesAlg.CreateEncryptor(aesAlg.Key, aesAlg.IV);
// Create the streams used for encryption.
using (MemoryStream msEncrypt = new MemoryStream())
{
using (CryptoStream csEncrypt = new CryptoStream(msEncrypt, encryptor, CryptoStreamMode.Write))
{
using (StreamWriter swEncrypt = new StreamWriter(csEncrypt))
{
//Write all data to the stream.
swEncrypt.Write(plainText);
}
encrypted = msEncrypt.ToArray();
}
}
}
// Return the encrypted bytes from the memory stream.
return encrypted;
}
```

Comment: Could it be because you didn't declare the variable `plain` that you are passing into `CryptoJS.enc.UTF8.stringify`?

Comment: No. I am getting all variables that are convertng to wordArray. resulting 0. So it display error "cannot stringify undefined"

Comment: Yes but, `var plaintext = CryptoJS.enc.UTF8.stringify(plain);`
What is `plain`? It's not defined in the code snippet.

Comment: Sorry. Plain will be decrypt that will be decrypted. I just testing code and change it. But getting problem with decrypt. It throws 0 arrays when i console

Comment: I just edit my question. Have a look now

Comment: Is there a reason why you are encoding your ciphertext, key and IV to hex before using them? From the encryption code, the hex encoding looks like extra steps

Comment: When i use them without hex conversion. Decrypt throws empty array

Answer (score 2):

I solved it. Here is the solution:

```
var strHexWA = (CryptoJS.lib.WordArray.create(new Uint8Array(cipherText)));             
        var KeyWA = (CryptoJS.lib.WordArray.create(new Uint8Array(Key)));
        var IVWA = (CryptoJS.lib.WordArray.create(new Uint8Array(IV)));
        var decrypt = CryptoJS.AES.decrypt({
            ciphertext: strHexWA
        }, KeyWA, {
            iv: IVWA,
            padding: CryptoJS.pad.Pkcs7,
            mode: CryptoJS.mode.CBC
        }); 
        var plaintext = decrypt.toString(CryptoJS.enc.Utf8);            
        return plaintext;
```

Answer (score 0):

`CryptoJS.enc.Hex.parse` parses a hex string to a word array. As seen in the documentation:

```
var words = CryptoJS.enc.Hex.parse("48656c6c6f2c20576f726c6421");
```

Seems like you want to convert a WordArray to a hex string instead, so you should use `CryptoJS.enc.Hex.stringify` instead.

Comment: It returns wordarray now. I need to convert it to string to drcypt data. How can i?

Comment: var plaintext = CryptoJS.enc.UTF8.stringify(decrypt); It throws error when i use this code

Comment: That's because it should be `CryptoJS.enc.Utf8.stringify`. Mind the casing.

Comment: Now it throws this error "Malformed UTF-8 data"

Comment: Check question please. I edited it with the result i need

Comment: The the question is: Are you decrypting it the same way as it was encrypted? You'll need to post the way it was encrypted, otherwise this will just be a wild goose chase.

Comment: It is encrypted in .net. Let me post it

Comment: I have a decryption code as well in .net. Let me know if you want to look at it